# How to compute this probability: uniform distribution of two random variables

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $p$ be a prime number. 
Let $i,j \in \{1, \dotsc, p-1\}$ be fixed numbers.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two random variables, where $A \in_{u.a.r} \{1,...,p-1\}$ and $B \in_{u.a.r} \{0,...,p-1\}$. 
Further, let $r \in \{1,...,p-1\}$ be a fixed number. 
Now I would like to Show that $$Pr[(Ai+B) \text{ mod } p < r \text{ AND } (Aj+B)\text{ mod }p < r ]= \frac{r (r-1)}{p(p-1)}$$

It Looks so easy and I have tried so many things but it does not work. Do you have any hint for me? 
It Looks to me like we should first fix $A$ and then look at the possibilities for $B$, so

$$Pr[(Ai+B) \text{ mod } p < r \text{ AND } (Aj+B)\text{ mod }p < r ]= \sum_{a} Pr[A=a] Pr[(ai+B) \text{ mod } p < r \text{ AND } (aj+B)\text{ mod }p < r]$$

But this does not help too much, neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to a counting argument.

Let $\Omega=\{(A,B): 1\leq A\leq p-1, 0\leq B\leq p-1\}$
 be the set of all possible outcomes. 
The number of these outcomes is $p(p-1)$ and they 
are all equally likely.

For fixed $i\neq j\in\{1,2,\dots, p-1\}$
and $0\leq m\leq p-1$, the subset 
${\cal S}=\{(A,B): Ai+B\pmod p=m\}$ has $p-1$ elements, 
one for each value of $A$. 
Therefore as $(A,B)$ ranges over $\cal S$,
 the values taken by 
$Aj+B=m+A(j-i) \pmod p$ are exactly 
$\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}\setminus \{m\}$. This is the place 
in the argument where we use the fact that $p$ is prime.
Do you see why?

For $0\leq m<r$, the set 
  $\{(A,B): Ai+B\pmod p=m, 0\leq Aj+B \pmod p<r\}$
has $r-1$ elements and taking the union over such 
$m$ shows that 
$\{(A,B): 0\leq Ai+B\pmod p<r, 0\leq Aj+B\pmod p<r\}$
has $r(r-1)$ elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. To count the possible combinations was also an idea I tried to pursue. So I like this solution very much.

But I have some questions. 
I do not get the sentence: "As (A,B) ranges over S, the values ...". 

We have that $S=\{(1,b_1), \dotsc (p-1, b_{p-1})\}$ (where $k i + b_k (mod p ) =m$) and in fact we have that $\{b_1, \dotsc, b_{p-1}\}=\{1,\dotsc, p-1\}$. 

Then, we consider $Aj + B = Ai +B - Ai + Aj = A(j-i) + m (mod p)$. For $i \neq j$ and thus $i-j (mod p) \in \{1, \dotsc, p-1\}$ we have that $A(j-i)$ takes the values $\{1, \dotsc, p-1\}$.

Comment: But why does $m + A(j-i) (mod p)$ take the values $\{0,...,p-1\} \setminus \{m\}$? 
I think this has to do something with the fact that we have a group for $p$ prime and thus every element has a unique inverse. But I cannot see this step.

Comment: That's correct, the value $A(j-i)$ takes on all non-zero values as $A$ runs through $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you very much! That helped a lot.